# Как в javascript определять модели

Tags: javascript

в Java  к примеру для каждого запроса и ответа создается POJO, где определяется поля которые будут в каком либо запросе или ответе, Принято ли такое создавать для Javascript, ведь это удобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java так принято, потому что по другому долгое время было и невозможно (не знаю как сейчас). Кроме того в Java понятны собственно плюсы такого подхода, а именно строгая типизация обеспечивает проверку времени компиляции, поддержку со стороны IDE и т.п.

В JavaScript создание дополнительных классов в целом никак вам не поможет. Кроме того некоторыми людьми это воспринимается преимуществом, т.к. повышает скорость прототипирования и разработки, снижают "шум" в коде. Однако по мере возникновения типизированных надстроек типа TypeScript возникают и аналогичные практики.

В общем и целом в голом JavaScript скорее такой практики скорее нет, строгую валидацию и типизацию как правило оставляют на server-side.

Comment: @JNat ничего по этому поводу не скажу, не пользовался.